# Why is the user logged out after submitting a form in django?

Tags: python, django

When I submit a form as a logged in user, I am suddenly logged out, as shown below. I'm not able to embed images yet because I don't have 10 reputation. Here are the linked images:

[Submitting the Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yhmF.png)

[After submitting the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJL2x.png)

**views.index**

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import User, Bid, Auction, Comment

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        title = request.POST["title"]
        bid = int(request.POST["startingBid"])
        category = request.POST["category"]
        image = request.POST["img"]
        description = request.POST["description"]

        listing = Auction(name=title, bid=bid,description=description,url=image, category=category)
        listing.save()

        listings = Auction.objects.all()

        #user.is_authenticated == True here
  
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
            "listings": listings,
            "user": request.user.username,
        })
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html")
```

**urls.py**

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("home", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("create", views.create, name="create"),
]
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>

    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
        Please login to see active listings.
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% for listing in listings %}
            <div class="card bg-light">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <img src="{% url 'listing.url' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="Listing image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h2>{{ listing.name }}</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h6>Starting Bid: ${{ listing.bid }}</h6>
                                    <p>Category: {{ listing.category }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <p>{{ listing.description }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <small class="text-muted">Created {{ listing.dateTime }}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**models.Auction and models.User**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Auction(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64,default="")
    bid = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),])
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="")
    dateTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=300, default="", blank=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

When the user submits the form, request.method in views.index equals "POST" and user.is_authenticated is True until the template is rendered. I want the user to be taken back to the index page. As shown in the images, "Please log in to see active listings." is being shown, meaning user.is_authenticated somehow becomes false. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, your **views.index** function should override login. Something like this

```
@login_required(login_url = "user:login")
def index(request):
```

Answer (score 0):

The template context variable `user` is set to the username - not the User instance:

```
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "listings": listings,
        "user": request.user.username,  # change to just request.user
    })
```

The user isn't logged out - the template simply checks the string username for a `is_authenticated` attribute but obviously finds none. `user.is_authenticated` is therefore always false.